# Adding cache headers to Nginx configuation file breaks the /admin area

Tags: cache, server, nginx

When I add this to my Nginx Confirguration file:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 7d;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

In the admin area I get all 404 responses on those assets (js, css, png, etc).

Without that in my configuration, for example, settings.css is OK:

```
Request URL:http://{site}admin/resources/css/settings.css?d=1411426522
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Expires:Sun, 11 Oct 2015 02:25:24 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 22 Sep 2014 22:55:22 GMT
Pragma:cache
```

And then with the code, the settings.css is 404 Not Found

```
Request URL:http://{site}/admin/resources/css/settings.css?d=1411426522
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Expires:Sat, 04 Oct 2014 02:31:56 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Craft rewrites the location of those files using a query string, which is what's causing nginx to lose track of them. Using the [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive should force nginx to find and serve them properly.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
  expires 7d;
  add_header Pragma "public";
  add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, extremely helpful. This should be in the Craft docs.